# What are the similarities between traditional internet and IoT (Internet of Things)?

Tags: web-services

I have found many differences between the two. However I need to find both the differences and similarities. I would assume that content creation is one of them,but they differ in who exactly creates it. Are there any more?

Comment: Welcome! A very similar question has already been asked, so I've marked this as a duplicate. If you have a separate question, or something more specific that's not covered in the duplicate, feel free to [edit] or ask another. Hope you find the linked question interesting.